# A sum related to the Mobius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

It is well-known that
$$\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu (d)}{d} \quad n\in \mathbb Z^+$$

Where $\phi $ is Euler's totient function and $\mu$ is the Mobius function. But using the formula for $\phi$ we get

$$\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu (d)}{d}$$

And if we pick $n=p_1\dots p_k$ where $p_i$ is the ith prime. We get

$$\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu (d)}{d}$$
But now the divisors of $n$ are somewhat easier to handle. Let $D_=\{d\in \mathbb N| d\mid n\}$ and $$D_j=\{d\in D\mid d \text{ has exacltly $j$ prime factors.}\}$$
Hence our product becomes $$\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{d\in D_i}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}$$
Here I got stuck. I want to get an explicit formula for the RHS but the inner sum is hard to evaluate. How can I evaluate the following sum $\sum_{d\in D_i}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}$. I think binomial coefficients will pop out.

Comment: What is the aim of these computations, is it to prove that $\prod_{i=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)=0$ ? or something else ?

Comment: There is no simple formula for $\pi_k:=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)$. Indeed, $\pi_k=\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)\pi_{k-1}$ so that
$$ p_k=\frac{1}{1-\frac{\pi_k}{\pi_{k-1}}} $$
You would have a nice formula for all the prime numbers which (un)fortunately does not exist.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "a formula" ? what should it look like ? what would be the goal of finding such a formula ? We can't help you if you don't provide more context.

Comment: You can evaluate $\mu(d)$ if you know $d\in D_i$

Comment: @Tuvasbien I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: @Tuvasbien I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $\ell \in [0,k]$,
$$\sum_{d \in D_\ell} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} = (-1)^\ell \sum_{i_1 \le \ldots \le i_\ell} \frac{1}{p_{i_1} \cdots p_{i_\ell}}.$$
When you add up these quantities, you just get the developed form of the product $$\prod_{i=1}^k \Big(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\Big).$$
As noted by Tuvasbien, there is no simple formula for the elementary symmetric polynomials of the inverses of the first $\ell$ primes numbers, otherwise it would be a formula giving the list of all prime numbers.